# How to easily type a template without copy paste?

Tags: macos, automator, text

Several times a day I type the same URL (in text form) into website forms. I would like a simple script (or Automator action) that types the URL where I have a cursor placed.

Answer (score 3):

You may find it easier to use text substitutions instead of using AppleScript or Automator.

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Text and, in the Replace and With columns, assigned the text you want to type and what it will be replaced with.

For example, type `url1` to have it replaced with `https://www.google.com` as shown in the image below.

When you do type the Replace text, a small pop-up will show with the With text, press the Spacebar key to have the substitution take place, or the Esc key to cancel the action.

[image]

Comment: [aText](https://trankynam.com/atext/) is a far better Text Expansion app than Apple’s built in Text Replacements because Apple’s is limited to Cocoa apps.  For instance, it won’t work in Firefox, where aText does.  Plus, it’s much, much more versatile.. you can use images in your text replacements.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Automator service with an AppleScript included.
A possible way to do it is with the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
   keystroke "yoururl"
end tell
```

A detailed description how to do it is available under this link: http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2013/04/insert-text-with-a-keystroke-in-any-application.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service (and add a shortcut for it) using the script below.

```
property myBrowser : "Google Chrome"
property URL1 : "http://www.disney.com"
property URL2 : "http://www.netflix.com"
property URL3 : "http://www.amazon.com"

on run
    activate me
    set chosenText to (choose from list ¬
        {"URL1", "URL2", "URL3"} with title ¬
        "URL SELECTOR" with prompt ¬
        "Select URL below:" cancel button name "  Forget it  " OK button name "    Yes, please!    " default items {"URL1"}) as text
    if (chosenText as text) is "false" then
        return
    else if chosenText is "URL1" then
        set the clipboard to URL1
    else if chosenText is "URL2" then
        set the clipboard to URL2
    else if chosenText is "URL3" then
        set the clipboard to URL3
    end if
    delay 0.25
    tell application myBrowser to activate
    delay 0.25
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
end run
```

It will provide a dialog box with 3 options. Edit the URLs using the ones you wish. You can add more copying the scheme.

[image]

Remember to put the browser you are using too. Also make sure you enabled the browser in the Accessibility area of the Security and Privacy settings.

[image]

Search for how to set up a service if you are not sure how to do it.